# How to format double value into string with 2 decimal places after dot and with separators of thousands?

Tags: ios, formatter

I have a double value in Objective-C and I need to place its value into label.
How should I format it into string with 2 decimal places after dot and with separators of thousands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), for example:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setPositiveFormat:@"#,##0.00" ];

NSString *string = [formatter stringFromNumber:[ NSNumber numberWithDouble:1234567.8901 ] ];
// string is now "1,234,567.89"
[formatter release];
```

Comment: That's OK, but if I got value without places after dot, I'd like to show "1,234,567.00". How can I do it?

Comment: @Metalier - apologies - I've changed the example.