# How to format a double into thousand separated and 2 decimals using java.util.Formatter

Tags: java

I want to format a double value into a style of having

1. Currency Format Symbol
2. Value rounded into 2 decimal places
3. Final Value with thousand separator

**Specifically using the java.util.Formatter class**

Example :-

```
double amount = 5896324555.59235328;
String finalAmount = "";
// Some coding
System.out.println("Amount is - " + finalAmount);
```

Should be like :- 
`Amount is - $ 5,896,324,555.60`

I searched, but I couldn't understand the Oracle documentations or other tutorials a lot, and I found this link which is very close to my requirement but it's not in Java - 
[How to format double value into string with 2 decimal places after dot and with separators of thousands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058600/how-to-format-double-value-into-string-with-2-decimal-places-after-dot-and-with)

Comment: You obviously didn't search enough... There's a lot of questions about Formatter class. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323502/how-to-set-thousands-separator-in-java about thousand separator..

Comment: ...and don't use double for currency. Use BigDecimal. ;)

Comment: @Jerry Andrews any reason in particular?

Comment: Sure--BigDecimal always gives you infinite precision. float and double operations will introduce rounding errors. The canonical example is always rounding. Consider this article (google's 3rd result on a search for "Java BigDecimal Currency"): https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_need_for_bigdecimal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to use the `java.util.Formatter`, this will work:

```
double amount = 5896324555.59235328;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);
formatter.format("$ %(,.2f", amount);
System.out.println("Amount is - " + sb);
```

Expanded on the sample code from the [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) page.

Comment: This is what I really expected. Thank you!

Comment: That's OK. And, if you want to abstract your code from the specific dollar sign, you should use `Currency.getInstance(locale).getSymbol(locale)`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `java.util.Formatter`, I would strongly suggest using [`java.text.NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), which comes with a built-in currency formatter:

```
double amount = 5896324555.59235328;
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
String finalAmount = formatter.format(amount);
System.out.println("Amount is - " + finalAmount); 
// prints: Amount is - $5,896,324,555.59
```

Comment: This method worked although it wasn't the Formatter class.. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `printf` and a format specification like

```
double amount = 5896324555.59235328;
System.out.printf("Amount is - $%,.2f", amount);
```

Output is

```
Amount is - $5,896,324,555.59
```

To round up to 60 cents, you'd need `59.5` cents (or more).

Answer (score 0):

You can user

```
NumberFormat usFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "US"));
usFormatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
usFormatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
formattedAmount = String.format("%s", usFormatter.format(value.doubleValue()));
```

123456789.123456 -> 123,456,789.12

123456789.9878 -> 123,456,789.99